# Unable to set header in HAProxy

Tags: cors, http-headers, haproxy

I'm trying to override **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** in the response headers (as in the browser's network monitor), from this

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

to this

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://my-domain.com

when the requested resource is an image (*.png) or a font (*.woff/2), every time I access the website at https://my-domain.com:8081. The requested 'Host: ' header for images is **my-domain.com**, while for fonts is **fonts.gstatic.com**.

For some reason, the header is not overridden when the requested resource is a woff font - tried with all the combinations under '# NOK' as described below.

What could I possibly be missing?

```
frontend HEADERS
    bind *:8081 ssl crt my_domain.pem
    capture request header origin len 128

    acl hostname hdr(host) -i my-domain.com:8081
    acl hostname_font hdr(host) -i fonts.gstatic.com
    acl images path_end .png
    acl fonts path_end .woff .woff2

    # OK
    use_backend SET_HEADER if hostname images

    # NOK
    # use_backend SET_HEADER if hostname_font fonts
    # use_backend SET_HEADER if fonts
    # use_backend SET_HEADER if hostname_font

    # Default
    use_backend NO_SET_HEADER

backend NO_SET_HEADER
    mode http
    balance leastconn

    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Host %[req.hdr(Host)]
    http-request set-header Host some-other-domain.com

    server SOME-OTHER-DOMAIN-BE-01 10.10.0.5:443 ssl verify none check weight 1
    server SOME-OTHER-DOMAIN-BE-02 10.10.0.6:443 ssl verify none check weight 1

backend SET_HEADER
    mode http
    balance leastconn

    http-response set-header Access-Control-Allow-Origin https://my-domain.com

    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Host %[req.hdr(Host)]
    http-request set-header Host some-other-domain.com

    server SOME-OTHER-DOMAIN-BE-01 10.10.0.5:443 ssl verify none check weight 1
    server SOME-OTHER-DOMAIN-BE-02 10.10.0.6:443 ssl verify none check weight 1
```

Comment: Unless you have some funky dns resolution, any requests for host fonts.gstatic.com should be going to google's servers directly.  HAProxy would receive none of them.

Comment: @mweiss so, you're saying this is the expected behavior?

Comment: Yes, I'm saying that under normal circumstances, you should not be receiving any requests that have Host: fonts.gstatic.com, since its ip address should be resolved to something google owns (for example, using nslookup fonts.gstatic.com, you can see that it resolves to a different ip than one you control, your-domain.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @mweiss this is actually the expected behavior - requests to fonts.gstatic.com never 'land' on the HAProxy host. Therefore, it's not possible to edit the header.